# Nginx - Rewrite Domain to Domain with full URL

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I need to setup nginx to rewrite "www.test.com" to "www.new-test.com/test/test?foo=bar&bar=foo". 
I've tried the following code:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name test.com www.test.com;

    access_log off;
    autoindex off;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ http://www.new-test.com/dir/test?foo=bar&bar=foo permanent;
    }
}
```

My problem is: "If you specify a ? at the end of a rewrite then Nginx will drop the original $args". Ok but i need to redirect to the full URL with Queries. How can i do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `$request_uri` or `$args` to any place you want in the URL and also use `return` with proper http return code `301` for example that is much better to tell the browser you are redirecting it to another place. Your configuration would be like :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.com www.test.com;

    access_log off;
    autoindex off;

    return 301 http://www.new-test.com/dir/test?foo=bar&bar=foo&$args;
    or
    ....
    return 301 http://www.new-test.com$request_uri/dir/test?foo=bar&bar=foo;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the use of return directive.

Comment: Can you share you config file please, or update your question, also share the url you try to access before getting the redirect and the url you got redirected to.

Comment: It works! Anybody added the "test.com" in another configuration-file so ... sorry! Thank you so much for your help and the return option :)